# $\mathbb{R}$ is not the field of fractions of a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I need to prove the following.

If $D$ is an UFD and if

$$\mathbb{R}\cong \operatorname{Frac}(D)$$

Then $\mathbb{R}\cong D$.

I have no idea how to prove it. I tried using the fact that the fraction field is a localisation and that localisation is flat.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: If $D$ had at least one prime element $p$, then $X^n - p$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$ by Gauss' lemma and Eisenstein's critertion for any $n>0$. This case cannot happen, since the algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$ has degree $2$ over $\Bbb R$. A UFD without any prime element being a field, we conclude that $D \cong \Bbb R$ as fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $p\in D$ is a prime element.  Then, as an element of $\mathbb{R}\cong\operatorname{Frac}(D)$, $p$ has a cube root.  What does this tell you?

Details of how to finish the argument are hidden below.

> It is a contradiction if $p$ has a cube root in $\operatorname{Frac}(D)$, as you can see by considering the factorizations in $D$ of the numerator and denominator of its cube root.  Thus $D$ has no prime elements, which implies every nonzero element of $D$ is a unit.  That is, $D$ is a field, so $D=\operatorname{Frac}(D)\cong\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, let $D$ be a UFD and $K=\operatorname{Frac}(D)$.

Then, $K^\times = D^\times \times A$, where $A$ is a free abelian group.

Moreover, $A$ is trivial iff $D$ is a field and $K=D$.
Otherwise, $A$ and so $K^\times$ admit a nonzero homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$.

Now, $\mathbb R^\times = \{1,-1\} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is the product of a torsion group by a divisible group and so admits only the zero homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1550024/589).

Bottom line: if $\mathbb R= \operatorname{Frac}(D)$, then $D=\mathbb R$.

Comment: $K^\times$ is the product of a free abelian group with the group of units of $D$. This doesn't change much of your argument, because a divisible group cannot have an abelian free group as quotient. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}^\times\cong\{1,-1\}\times\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})}$. Also $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is not divisible, but is the product $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times\{1,-1\}$, where $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is divisible.

Comment: @egreg, perhaps now? thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

By Eisenstein's criterion, there are irreducible polynomials of any degree in $(\operatorname{Frac} D)[X]$ if $D$ is a UFD but not a field.